# Как найти в строке слова с разной кодировкой?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, парсер

Всем привет!
Хочу понять как проще найти в строке/массиве слово, в котором содержатся и русские и английские слова?
Спасибо!

Как я вижу решение, берем массив слов и проверяем регуляркой, если в слово есть и русские и английские буквы, то значит оно с ошибкой, при этом стоп-символы отбрасываем.

Comment: Ммм... лучше не мутить такие кастыли а контент менеджеру сказать что бы не копипастил названия а вводил нормально, плюс поставить проверку если есть слове смешение букв то ошибка

Comment: Есть конкретная задача, найти в слове кривые буквы, по ошибки иногда можно написать вместо русской А, английскую A . Тут контент менеджер не углядит.

Comment: Вы случаем не в компание с именем 'А....н' работаете? Хах буква 'а' английская и русская расположена в разных местах, я к примеру не знаю как можно написать одну букву на английском потом на русском... Я так понимаю вам для поиска по сайту?

Comment: Вы просто не сталкивались с большим объемам данных, когда в день по 100-200 тысяч символов пишут разные люди, нужно проверять не только на уникальность, водность, но и на такие ляпы. Есть что по теме подсказать?

Comment: Полагаю, нужно использовать что-то вроде [этой](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) функции, или заранее заготовленные наборы символов с проверкой принадлежности каждого символа слова какому-то из этих наборов, если всё в UTF-8.

Comment: Сталкивался... Но всё зависит от того что вы хотите? именно какая тематика сайта и что за функционал.

Comment: Я в вопросе написал, то как я вижу решение, возможно оно не правильное. Тематика вообще тут не причем, функция mb-detect-encoding к сожалению кривая.

Comment: она только кодировку проверяет а не конкретный символ. Это не оптимально 100 слов по 10 символов это как миниму 1000 проходов а если учесть проверку на 2 языка то патерн 28+33 и того 61+1000 уже 61000 проходов....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/[a-z]/ism', $var) && preg_match('/[а-яё]/ismu', $var)){
    // в $var есть и русские и английские буквы
}
```

Так попроще и понадёжнее и со стоп-символами возится не надо имхо...

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно именно так и хотел сделать, но не получалось. Итог: <?php
 
$string = "работа bАГ рAбOтА blа blа bla";
$tempArray = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($tempArray as $word){
    if(preg_match('/[a-z]/ism', $word) && preg_match('/[а-яё]/ismu', $word)){
    // в $var есть и русские и английские буквы
    echo $word.", ";}
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "bla blа bla";
$tempArray = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($tempArray as $word){
    if(mb_ereg("[a-zA-Z]", $word) && mb_ereg("[^\x00-\x7F]", $word)){
        echo $word," is incorrect";
    }
}
```

Все "английские символы" входят в 7-битную таблицу ASCII (туда так же входят различные спецсимволы, которые заведомо не являются русскими буквами)

`mb_ereg("[^\x00-\x7F]", $word)` вернет TRUE, если в слове присутствуют НЕ английские символы и НЕ знаки препинания из стандартного набора.

Естественно он с одинаковой радостью найдет и китайские иероглифы и эмодзи, но, как мне кажется, у вас основная проблема именно в определении наличия символов латинского алфавита.

Comment: Вы знаете алгоритм регулярного выражения?

Comment: @Naumov боюсь я не понял ваш вопрос

Comment: Ну как работает регулярное выражение в php?

Comment: @Naumov как регулярное выражение. Давайте закончим игру в загадки и скажите уже, что конкретно вам не понравилось, и если вы правы - я извинюсь и поправлю.

Comment: алгоритм просто не однозначный, при большом объёме может тормозить

Comment: @Naumov ну так это вечная тема компромисса между скоростью работы и количеством функционала. Вообще, насколько я понимаю, mb_ereg должен заканчивать поиск после первого же найденного символа, да и шаблон элементарный, не должен откатов вызывать.

Comment: Спасибо, я где-то предполагал такое выражение, только поиск в слове сперва A-z и обязательно а-Я , тогда точно было бы понятно, что есть подмена букв, спасибо за ваш вариант.

Comment: Протестил, не рабочий вариант https://yadi.sk/i/f1zmGL_JvzcfU

Comment: @sanitarn ну забыл экранирование убрать при замене preg_match на mb_ereg. Бывает.